# How to characterize the group of homeomorphisms of unit disk in terms of the group of homeomorphisms of plane?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-theory, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of homeomorphisms of unit disk $(D)$ fixing boundary point wise and $P$ be the group of homeomorphisms of plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Can we characterize $G$ in terms of $P$. Speaking precisely, can we have the result of the form: $\gamma$ is in $G$ if and only if $F(\gamma)$ is in $P$, where $F$ is some  condition or some function (for example it could be in terms of euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

We can easily embedd $G$ in $P$ as:
Define a homeomorphism $g:Int(D)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ in polar coordinates as $g(r,\theta)=(\frac{r}{1-r},\theta)$. Then the function $f:G\rightarrow P$ defined by $f(\gamma)=g^{-1}\gamma g$ is an embedding. Through $f$ we can study the image of $G$ in $P$ rather than $G$ itself.

Comment: How can $g$ be a homeo?  One is compact and one is not.

Comment: Sorry, $g$ is defined on the interior of $D$. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer is this.

For $h \in P$, let $\phi(h) : D \to  \phi(D)$ denote the restriction of $h$ (which is a homeomorphism). Then $\phi(h) \in G$ if and only if $h(x) = x$ for all $x \in S^1 = \partial D$.

The "only if" part is trivial. Conversely, assume  $h(x) = x$ for all $x \in S^1$. We know that $S^1$ separates the plane into two connected components $\mathring{D}$ = open unit disk (which is contractible) and $D' = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus D$ (which is not contractible). $h(\mathring{D})$ must be one of these connected components. But $h(\mathring{D}) \approx \mathring{D}$ is contractible, whereas $h(D') \approx D'$ is not. This shows that $h(\mathring{D}) = \mathring{D}$, i.e. $h(D) = D$. Thus $\phi(h) \in G$.

Edited:

Here are some examples of homeomorphisms of the plane which fix $S^1$ pointwise.

1) Let $f : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous map such that $f(1) = 0$. Define
$$h(z) =
\begin{cases}
e^{if(\lvert z \rvert)}z & z  \ne 0 \\
0 & z = 0
\end{cases}
$$
In the first line we use the complex multiplication on $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$. Note that $\lvert e^{if(\lvert z \rvert)} \rvert = 1$, i.e $h$ maps each circle with radius $r$ around $0$ homeomorphically onto itself.

2) Let $g : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be any continuous strictly monotonic increasing function such that $g(0) = 0, g(1) = 1$ and $g(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$. Define
$$h(z) = g(\lvert z \rvert) z .$$

Comment: It seems you are only characterizing those maps of disc which arise as the restrictions of the homeomorphisms $h$ of a plane. That is, such restricted maps will be in $G$ if and only if $h$ fixes circle point wise. Isn't it so? What about those maps of a disc which are not restrictions of the homeomorphisms of plane? Won't they generate their own class in the group $G$, in a similar manner you have provided the characterization for the 'restricted maps?

Comment: Each $g  \in G$ extends (non.uniquley) to an element of $P$. The elements of $P$ obtained in that way are precisely those in my answer.

Comment: What would be an explicite examples of such homeomorphisms $h$ of a plane which fix circle point wise?  If I take $h=(x,y)$ on $S^1$ and $(x+2,y+2)$ everywherelse, is this the homeomorphism of plane?

Comment: I shall add some examples to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I would appreciate!

Comment: By the way, the map $t(x,y) = (x+2,y+2)$ is a translation. It does not keep $S^1$ fixed So the map which fixes $S^1$ and is $= t$ everywhere else is neither continuous nor bijective.

Comment: Thank you very much adding the examples!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88504/discussion-between-ersh-and-paul-frost).